# Error log missing when launching Anypoint Studio

Tags: java, macos, java-8, mule, anypoint-studio

I'm trying to get my Mac set up to use Mulesoft and Anypoint Studio but when I launch Anypoint, I get the following message:

```
An error has occurred.
See the log file
/Users/me/AnypointStudio/studio-workspace/.metadata/.log
```

When I go to that path, the studio-workspace directory is empty so there/s no .metadata/.log file. Without an error message I'm at a loss as to how to go about troubleshooting this issue.

Running on Mac OS. Here's what I get when I run `java -version`

```
java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a terminal, try `less +G /Users/me/AnypointStudio/studio-workspace/.metadata/.log`. To exit, hit `'q'`.